# how to pass url without http through email

Tags: php, email, deep-linking

I just want to pass `brushit://user_id=10` from email. Is that possible creating a hyperlink like

```
<a href="brushit://user_id=10" > Click</a>
```

This is not working

Comment: What? you want to pass it where exactly?

Comment: Certainly you can define such a link. But that assumes that the `brushit` protocol scheme is registered and has been assigned a valid handler on the client machine.